# Questions with making calls to an API

Tags: ruby, httparty

I've been working on creating a CLI gem for a job board. I've been setting up my API class, but I have been struggling to get it to work correctly in terms of successful calls; I'm using HTTParty to parse. When I have been testing this, it keeps giving me a method error for "[]". I've gone over everything, made sure the syntax is correct but have hit a wall in figuring out what seems to break this. Here is the method I created to list all of the jobs on the specific board:

```
def all_jobs_call
  url = "https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/flatironschoolcareers/jobs"
  response = HTTParty.get(url)
  response["absolute_url"]["location"]["metadata"]["id"]["title"].each do |job|
    absolute_url = job["absolute_url"]
    location = job["location"]
    metadata = job["metadata"]
    id = job["id"]
    title = job["title"]
  end
end
```

I would greatly appreciate any insight as to what I could be doing wrong or if I'm missing something glaring. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The JSON response you get from https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/flatironschoolcareers/jobs looks like this:

```
{
  "jobs": [
    {
      "absolute_url": "https://boards.greenhouse.io/flatironschoolcareers/jobs/4460392002",
      "internal_job_id": 4375855002,
      "location": {
        "name": "New York, NY"
      },
      "metadata": [
        {
          "id": 4019377002,
          "name": "Employment Type",
          "value": "Full-time",
          "value_type": "single_select"
        },
      ...
```

HTTParty converts that response to Ruby objects. So just like in that JSON response, `response` has a top level `"jobs"` key which contains an array of jobs.

In order to get the 1st job you'd use:

```
response["jobs"][0]
#=> {"absolute_url"=>"https://boa...", "internal_job_id"=>4375855002, ...}
```

and to get it's `absolute_url`:

```
response["jobs"][0]["absolute_url"]
#=> "https://boards.greenhouse.io/flatironschoolcareers/jobs/4460392002"
```

And to traverse all jobs you call `each` on the array, i.e.:

```
response["jobs"].each do |job|
  puts job["absolute_url"]
end
```

Output:

```
https://boards.greenhouse.io/flatironschoolcareers/jobs/4460392002
https://boards.greenhouse.io/flatironschoolcareers/jobs/4460383002
https://boards.greenhouse.io/flatironschoolcareers/jobs/4472889002
...
```